# NServiceBus Full duplex bus callback with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

Project Source: [on github](https://github.com/sanelib/WebStarterKit)

Client is ASP.net Web API with OWIN and IIS host. Server is console.

I am having a scenario in which current thread has to wait till NSB completes its function. But my thread is waiting indefinitely from NSB reply.

```
var synchronousHandle = _bus.Send<MyCommand>(m => { m.TokenId = tokenId; })
    .Register(r => 
    {
        var completionResult = r.AsyncState as CompletionResult;
        if (completionResult == null || completionResult.Messages.Length <= 0) return;
        // Always expecting one IMessage as reply
        var response = completionResult.Messages[0];
    }, null);

synchronousHandle.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

In my Handler:

```
Bus.Reply(new GenericResponseMessage { IsSuccess = true });
```

Problem:

Code run without any error and client message queue receives response from Bus.Reply. But callback does not receives response.

Comment: hi Sunny, i'm having the same problem.  i looked at your code.  how are you sending messages back from the nservicebus server to your client?

Comment: I use Bus.Reply. but that does not work. If you can figure out cause then let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Will [this doco help?](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/using-nservicebus-with-asp.net-mvc)

In your code it is commented out (https://github.com/sanelib/WebStarterKit/blob/da796e69826072ae78443c7952cf2669d74a9ee7/DotNetServer/src/NSBus.Server/CommandHandlers/UserGrantAccessHandler.cs#L70)

Another option is to use signalR (would be a more reliable option IMHO) Take a look at [Roy's blog post](http://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/an-nservicebus-backplane-for-signalr/)